# Using sed to insert php variable to text document?

Tags: php, variables, sed, exec

I am trying to insert a php variable into a text document using sed. My issue is that I am not able to get the variable into the document only the actual variable name is printed. I have searched and seen some similar questions, but none of the methods / answers got me to a point where this will work and am trying to figure out what I am doing incorrect here.

```
exec('sed "7a\$data" /path/to/file/rss.txt > /path/to/file/rsstmp.txt') ;
```

I am taking the $data variable and inserting it into the 7th line of a document then saving it as a different filename. The variable does hold a value, when echo'd it returns the correct values, it just won't insert the value into the document.

Any help or point in the right direction will be helpful.

Edit - Here is the full statement:

```
 if (!empty($_GET['act2'])) {
 foreach (glob("/path/to/file/*.txt") as $filename) {
     $before = '<item><title>Agenda</title><link>www.website.com</link>
<description>' ;
     $after = '</description></item>' ;
     $data = file_get_contents($filename) ;
     $data = htmlentities($before) . $textfile . htmlentities($after) ;
 // insert $data into 7th line of rss doc    
 exec("sed '7a\\$data' /path/to/file/rss.txt > /path/to/file/rsstmp.txt") ;
// Verify $data holds a value      
 echo $data;
}
```

Comment: There's a difference between double-quoting a string and single-quoting it. Because you're using single quotes, you're passing the literal string `$data` to exec. If you switch the double quotes to single ones and vice versa, it ought to work.

Comment: Thanks andrewsi, but it still outputs the same results (just the actual variable name "$data") instead of the content. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can try swapping the `exec` to an `echo` to see what it's actually generating?

Comment: Using echo just returns the above string as seen between the brackets, if I use echo $data  its returns the correct value.

Comment: Oh, I see! We're now escaping the `$`. What exactly is the value of that first parameter? I think we need to add an extra backslash in there: try `'7a\\$data'` - that should come out as `'7a\<value>'`

Comment: Escaping as shown completely emptied my file. Removed original data and did not insert any new data. Essentially I am taking text documents and trying to create an RSS feed out of them for internal use. We have a powerful RSS reader that can filter these docs for us. Above is the full code, the txt documents contain basic text data. Although maybe the html I am wrapping the data in is throwing off the output somehow?

Comment: Could you edit your question with a sample of the working command line? I'm guessing it should be something like `sed '7a/something' ....`?